# Getting people's email addresses into a spreadsheet?

Tags: email

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to collect email addresses on my website for free and have them automatically put in a spreadsheet.  It will be very simple-first name, last name and email address.  The best solution I've found at the moment is using a Google Docs form which adds them to a spreadsheet, I'm just not a big fan of the Google Docs logos all over it for a few reasons.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Seems like a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Fault may not be the best place to ask this question. It would might find people more willing to respond to a web-related question at either:

[Doctype.com](http://doctype.com/), for help on putting a page together yourself or [HowToGeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/), to find an automated systme similar to Google Docs. Services like WuFoo can collect data for you and also provide nice interfaces to create forms and download Excel sheets of the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're able to execute php code it seems like there's   [at least one php class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1919.html)  that may do the job for you. EDIT: Also http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel/.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting them:
PHP script -> MySQL database

Getting them into a spreadsheet (why spreadsheets are still used, I have no idea):
PHP script -> download CSV file
open CSV file in OpenOffice Calc, or whatever spreadsheet program you use.